# Why would adding <?php exit;?> to the end of a file make a page load quicker?

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, apache

I have a WordPress site that became noticeably slower last week (load time increased from ~2 seconds up to ~7 seconds).

During my troubleshooting, I added `<?php exit; ?>` to the bottom of our *footer.php* file. The footer.php file is included at the bottom of each page using `<?php get_footer(); ?>`.

This reduced the page load time back down to ~2 seconds but I don't know why.

**Is there any reason why adding `<?php exit; ?>` to the end of a file would make a page load quicker?**

*footer.php* without `<?php exit; ?>`

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

*footer.php* with `<?php exit; ?>`

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
<?php exit; ?>
```

a sample page template in my WordPress theme

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content">
  ...
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

***Edit #1, per suggestions from @manassehkatz:***

The resulting HTML for the page is the same for both versions of the `footer.php` file. Disabling all WordPress plugins had no effect.

Comment: i supose that break any more php execution and free memory

Comment: as Alvaro said, there's probably more going on after the footer is sent to client.

Comment: Is there a way to debug this in PHP or on the server?

Comment: Take a look at the resulting HTML in the browser (e.g., View Source) and see what, if anything, is sent with and without the exit command. If they are the same, there may some after the HTML processing - possibly some WordPress plugins - that is doing more work behind the scenes- try turning off (temporarily) any plugins that you aren't actively using.